# Metric for pointwise convergence of monotone functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Does there exist a metric on the set of all monotone functions defined on a given compact set in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and taking values in  a given compact set in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that convergence in this metric is equivalent to pointwise convergence?

Monotonicity in both domain and image is understood in the component-wise partial order sense.

Comment: If $m>1$, please explain what you mean by "monotone functions".

Comment: @uniquesolution, as indicated above, I mean the component-wise order. But let's for simplicity consider $k=1$ and $m=1$.

Comment: So you order $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k$ as $x\leq x'$ iff $x_i\leq x'_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$? And similarly for the target space $\mathbb{R}^l$?

Comment: @Freeze_S, yes this is the component-wise partial order I am using.

Comment: Actually, is the topology of pointwise convergence metrizable?

Comment: @JohnMa, I don't think so but I consider monotone functions only. Can it be metrizable on the set of those functions only?

Comment: In general, over large enough domain, no! It is locally convex though. That is already pretty nice feature as it comes very close to metric spaces already: The topology is induced by seminorms. But it may still miss topological properties as being first countable.

Comment: @MerylStreep: You might try to find criteria which guarantee that your topology is metrizable like: Urysohn's theorem, cardinality of seminorms, bounded neighborhoods. However, the first to pretty much will fail. For the last one consult Rudin, Functional Analysis. *(There's a more readable version as PDF file on the internet from a different author though it is a plagiat!!)*

Comment: @Freeze_S, thanks, appreciate your help! Will check all that.

Comment: @MerylStreep: After all, do you really need it to be metrizable or is it just for convenience?

Comment: @MerylStreep: You're welcome!! :)

Comment: @Freeze_S, I am not sure I absolutely need it to be metrizable. I am just more comfortable working with metrics to be honest…

Comment: @MerylStreep: Yep that's what I thought so: For locally convex spaces there's no big difference to metric spaces at least not for the matter of convenience. The topology is even defined w.r.t. seminorms: $\mu_x(f):=\|f\|_x:=|f(x)|$ ('mu': **M**inkowski gauge!)